# Can somebody explain to me that how does this C program reverse an characters array?

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse

there is a program written below. I am not understanding that how does it reverse an char array. I mean it works fine, it does reverse the string which is stored in char array by user, but I want to know how does it work and how does it reverse the order? Basically I am not understanding the first for loop, it does not have any statements in the body plus the first part of the for loop is missing. Please explain in simple and easy words, not in typical or difficult words. I am not a native English speaker. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[99];
    int counter=0;

    cin >> name;

    for(;name[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
    {}

    cout << "\nName: ";

    for (;counter > 0; counter--)
    {
        cout << name[counter-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: First loop: [C-style strings are null-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), so what will the value of counter be after the loop?

Comment: The value of counter would be equal to the value of elements in the `char` array

Comment: Here's a really novel idea. Fire up your debugger and step through the code to follow exactly what it does. You not only learn how to read code and what it means, but you practice the very useful skills of using a debugger and problem solving, as well as what to do when you don't have someone around to give you a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C strings are null ('\0') terminated. The first loop increments `counter` until the end of the string contained in `name` is found. That is indicated by the null character. The important part is that `counter` is declared outside of the first `for` loop and it stays in scope, and with the same value, when the second loop is executed. The second loop then starts at the end of the string in `name` printing the characters until the it prints the first character.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but I still have some questions:

1. Why does the first for loop contains an array `name[counter]` in comparison part instead of just the `counter`?
2. Why does not the second loop contain `=` as well with the `>` sign in comparison part, because the first element of array is on 0th index, so how would it print that if the loop does not contain the `=` sign?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Answers. 1. The code is looking for the null terminator ('\0') in `name`. So it has to check `name[counter]`. 2. The `>` is used because the indexing into `name` is `counter - 1`. If the loop executed when `counter` was 0 `name[-1]` would be printed, and that is beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Because it does not know the length of `name`, it iterates until it finds a `\0` marking the end of the string. Naturally this same code could have been written an infinite different ways some of which it could know the length beforehand.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAlbers and Havenard. One more thing. Why does not the first loop's body contain any statement? Is it legal to write a loop without any statements in its body and would it work properly?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar _"Is it legal to write a loop without any statements in its body and would it work properly? "_ Obviously it is.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar It is perfectly legal. There are no statements because the only purpose of the first loop is to increment `counter`.

Comment: Thanks guys, for explaining this program and removing some other confusions

Answer (score 0):

In Your Program, First For loop is to know number of characters in name variable.
Let me explain you how it works.
For loop have basic structure like
    for(i=10;i>0;i--)
    {
          
//Body part of for
    }

First part i=0 is initialization, second part is condition and third part is Increment/Decrements. 
In your program, We have already initialize value of counter as 0.
 This loop is just for counting number of characters so after every loop count variable will increment. We do not need to write anything in body part.
after completing first for loop count variable have same value as name variable's characters.

Again in second loop we don't need to initialize count values because count already have some value stored in it.

Hope You understand now..!!

Answer (score -1):

you start your counter at 0.

```
for(;name[counter]!='\0'; counter++){}
```

the for loop above increments the counter until it reaches '\0' .At this point your counter has incremented to the number of characters of what you typed as name. eg: if you typed hello counter is now at 5.

`for (;counter > 0; counter--){cout << name[counter-1];
}`

In the above for loop,you start by having the counter value at 5 then printing out each character of your array in reverse because first iteration your counter is 5, you print name[4] which is o then counter decrements so you print name[3]=l,then name[2]=l,
then name[1]=e , then name[0] =h. Note: if your counter is at value n you are printing n-1. so when your counter decrements to 1 you print name[0]. then the counter finally decrements to  0 where the loop becomes false. Also you are not reversing the array elements themselves but are just printing them in reverse.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[99];
    int counter=0; // variable to store the number of characters in name.

    cin >> name;

    // the for loop is counting each letter until the end of the string, storing the result in counter.
    for(;name[counter]!='\0'; counter++)
    {}

    cout << "\nName: ";

    // if the name you entered was "Billy" counter would = 5
    for (;counter > 0; counter--)
    {
        // since counter = 5 counter subtracts 1 to get to the "5th" spot in the array which is when counter = 4
        // name[0] = B
        // name[1] = i
        // name[2] = l
        // name[3] = l
        // name[4] = y
        // now starting from position 4 in the array counter-- subtracts 1 
        // from counter each time it runs through the loop to get to each previous letter.
        cout << name[counter-1];
    }
}
```